# ionic run android is not working

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to run android application in my device,I tried commands  `ionic build android`
 and `ionic run android`.But no error message is showing.

[image]

system ionic configuration is,

[image]

Please help me?Thanks in advance

Comment: have you added the android platform? `ionic platform add android`

Comment: I  have added android platoform

Comment: `ionic cordova build android` this will build apk file in platform>android>build>output>apk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Changing Nodejs `v5.0.0` to `v4.2.0` resolved my issue.

Comment: it works for me. I used nvm to install the multiple node versions and use node 4.2.0 for ionic. Would be interesting to see why ionic does not run on 5.0.0

Comment: @ShyamVisamsetty:Glad to help you

Answer (score 4):

after this command

```
ionic build android
```

you got the following output after successfull build.---

```
Built the following apk(s):
/**/***/***/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
```

then run command for install your application in device

```
adb install platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
```

if you want to test on browser then simply run

```
ionic serve
```

Comment: are you setup ionic framework correctly in your system?   http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html follow this link for setup your ionic frmwork .

Comment: Yeah.Ionic info is added in my question

Comment: set path on cmd to your project location then execute build command.

Answer (score 2):

Update your Node and NPM package using command

**npm update -g** : (g for all global packages)

then run the command -

**ionic platform add android** : It will add the platform

Finally hit the command -

**ionic cordova build android**

**Note** : cordova package must be installed

Answer (score 0):

first run this command - cordova platform add android

a.  cordova platform remove android (for removing the platform when required)

cordova platform add ios

a.  cordova platform remove ios (for removing the platform when required)

i.  After adding platform, add the below in build.gradle at the end of the file.
configurations

```
{
all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'supportv4'
}
```

cordova build android

cordova build ios

cordova run android

cordova run ios